# I have HTTP scheme and HTTPS is expected, but my binding is BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport; And my EndPoint is HTTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, soap

I had an authentication problem with my Soap Client, which was not receiving the credentials correctly. It is a basic authentication (username and password), and apparently it was a binding problem.

For the authentication problem I jumped this problem:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: 'The HTTP request is not authorized with the "Anonymous" client authentication scheme. The authentication header received from the server was "Basic realm="SAP NetWeaver Application Server [PRD/400]"".'

To resolve it use `binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;`. But now I have a new problem that says:

> System.ArgumentException: 'The supplied URI scheme "http" is invalid; "https" was expected. Arg_ParamName_Name'

What I don't understand is why it tells me that the scheme is HTTP and expects HTTPS, when I'm using a BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport, which provides security is HTTPS

```
 BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(); 
 binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;

 SoapClient client = new SoapClient(binding, endpoint);
 client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = _userName;
 client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = _password;                
 await client.OpenAsync();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZNVJ.png)

**EDIT:**

Now im trying to use  `BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);`

But this gives me the same first error:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: 'The HTTP request is not authorized with the "Anonymous" client authentication scheme. The authentication header received from the server was "Basic realm="SAP NetWeaver Application Server [PRD/400]"".'

Answer (score 0):

```
 binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
```

Sets it to HTTPS, but you are passing something that is HTTP. If endpoint is HTTP and not HTTPS it will fail.

Comment: Yes, my endpoint is HTTP, I added to the title now.

Comment: That's why you get the exception, the endpoint needs to be HTTPS if you are using  binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;

Comment: And what I have to use if it is http?

Comment: You can't use HTTP with BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport, that's what i was answering from with your original question, but it appears you have changed your question again. Per the documentation TransportCredentialOnly or None will work with HTTP, so if it's not working there is likely a configuration issue, but without you sharing the rest of the config it's hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: 'The HTTP
> request is not authorized with the "Anonymous" client authentication
> scheme. The authentication header received from the server was "Basic
> realm="SAP NetWeaver Application Server [PRD/400]"".'

A wrong password can also be the cause of this error message.
Make sure that the configuration of the server and client is the same.